# Ack search for literal strings

Tags: grep, regex

I am sick of having to escape things when I want to search for part of an html tag.

How can I ack search for exactly what I type ***without*** having to escape stuff?

e.g.

```
ack-grep 'console.log(foo'
```

I get:

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/console.log( <-- HERE par/
```

Comment: Use a different shell?  Put it in quotes?  Place your search string in a file, I suspect ack-grep can get the string from a file.  Perhaps you can even could even get the search via stdin.

Comment: @Zoredache I added a better example.. I don't want to have to escape `(`.. and what do you mean by better shell?

Comment: I mean all the chracters you are complaining about are handled by your shell (bash/zsh/whatever).  The problem has nothing to do with the tool.  The problem is that the shell is not sending what you type.

Comment: Ah I think i found it.. -Q uses it literally..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to escape the regex.

```
ack 'console\.log\(foo'
```

(You should escape the `.` so that you don't match "consoleflog", because `.` matches any single character)

And if you would rather not do that, do this to quote every metacharacter automatically.

```
ack -Q 'console.log(foo'
```

Comment: \Q does not work on my server.  `ack '\Qconsole.log(foo'
ack: Invalid regex '\Qconsole.log(foo':
  Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\Qconsole.log( <-- HERE foo/`

Comment: I was mistaken about the `\Q` example and have removed it from the answer.  Thanks, @Sébastien.